# Mover um objeto na direção do "onmousemove"

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas, 2d

Estou tentando mover um objeto na direção em que a pessoa pressiona a tela, move e depois solta. Tentei usar alguns laços **for** (foi a única coisa que pensei) mas sem sucesso.

[se não deu bem pra entender segue a imagem de como seria][image: Como é pra ser]

Estou usando o canvas do HTML5 e JavaScript.

**EDITADO**

O meu código até o momento

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Canvas</title>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="482"></canvas>
 </center>
 <script>
  var canvas   = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var touchX, touchY;
  var objetos = [];

  setInterval(function(){
   atualizaCanvas();
   atualizaPos();
  }, 25);

  function atualizaCanvas(){
   contexto.fillStyle = "#f0f0f0";
   contexto.fillRect(0, 0, 320, 482);
   for(var x in objetos){
    contexto.fillStyle = objetos[x].cor;
    contexto.fillRect(objetos[x].x, objetos[x].y, 20, 20);
   }
  }

  function atualizaPos(){
   for(var x in objetos){
    if(objetos[x].xComeco != objetos[x].xFinal){
     objetos[x].x += (objetos[x].xFinal - objetos[x].xComeco)/10;
    }
    objetos[x].y -= 10;
    if (objetos[x].y <= -10){
     delete objetos[x];
    }
   }
  }

  canvas.onmousedown = function(evento){
   touchX = evento.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   touchY = evento.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  };

  canvas.onmouseup = function(evento){
   var ttX = evento.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
   var ttY = evento.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
   if (ttY < touchY){
    objetos.push({
     x: touchX,
     y: touchY,
     cor: "red",
     xComeco: touchX,
     xFinal: ttX
    });
   }
  };
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o código de o que já começou a fazer?

Comment: Mostre seu código, por favor. Em geral, se você quer que uma animação aconteça num canvas sem interação do usuário (i.e. o objeto continue se movendo depois do ponto B) você provavelmente deve usar `getAnimationFrame`. Ou no máximo um `setTimeout` ou `setInterval`. Essa parte você já sabe fazer, ou tem dúvida? Para a pergunta não ficar muito ampla, contextualize melhor, diga o que você sabe fazer e o que ainda está te trazendo dificuldade.

Comment: Eu fui tentando um pouco mais e cheguei em um código que até chega perto do esperado `for(var x in objetos){... objetos[x].x += (objetos[x].xFinal - objetos[x].xComeco)/10; ...`,  `xComeco` é a posição X onde a pessoa começou a pressionar a tela e `xFinal` é a posição X onde a pessoa parou de pressionar.